# Instantiate ViewModel data with Generic Protocols

Tags: ios, swift

So basically I'm trying to define one generic viewmodel protocol from which I would be able to define all other viewmodels ... but data in them would need to stay generic ... lets say I define protocol like below:

```
protocol GenericVMProtocol {
    associatedtype T

    var items: [T] { get }
}
```

Next, I conform my VM to it and define data:

```
class VM: GenericVMProtocol {
    typealias T = String
    var items: [String] = ["A", "B" , "C"]
}
```

For now everything is working as expected, but problems happen when I want to conform my VC to VMProtocol like so:

```
class VC: UIViewController {

    var vm: GenericVMProtocol

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        vm = VM()
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    func items() {
        print(vm.items)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

Im getting error:

> Protocol 'GenericVMProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint
>   because it has Self or associated type requirements

... And I must say I'm pretty clueless if I'm missing some logic or my thinking is wrong .. so I would appreciate any help! Tnx :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a `PAT` (protocol associated type) problem you cannot directly use `GenericVMProtocol` as type because again `it has associated type requirements` in your case

I dont know if the following will help you but the correct way to use a protocol with generic constraint is as follow :

```
protocol GenericVMProtocol {
associatedtype T

var items: [T] { get }
init()
}

class VM: GenericVMProtocol {
    typealias T = String
    var items: [String] = ["A", "B" , "C"]
    required init() {}
}

class VC<T>: UIViewController where T:GenericVMProtocol {


var vm: T

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    vm = T()
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

func items() {
    print(vm.items)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError()
}
}
```